# How do I force arity in lodash / underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I often find myself wanting force unary arity in `map` iterators, such that only the first argument – item value – is passed through (leaving out the key / index and iterator), to avoid overloading composed functions.

An example of a situation where I need this is the following:

```
var parts = [
    'projectIds',
    [ 1, 6, 7 ],
    'properties',
    [ 'name', 'startDate' ]
];

function pathFrom( parts ){
    return _( parts )
        // This is the tricky bit:
        .map( _.partialRight( _.result, 'toString' ) )
        .join( '/' )
        .valueOf();
};

alert( pathFrom( parts ) );
```

My desired output is `projectIds/1,6,7/properties/name,startDate`, but it actually ends up as `p/6/o/`, because the iteration index is passed on and plucked from the value (`p` is `'projectIds'[0]`, `6` is `[1,6,7][1]`, `o` is `'properties'[2]`, etc).

How can I lock the arity of the map iterator such that only the first argument is pulled through, and the rest discarded?

Comment: Why are you using `partialRight` and `result` at all?

Comment: @Bergi I assume you're implying a 'there is no spoon' solution, by virtue that the items will be coerced toString via `join` anyway. But the code above is a simplified example – my actual chain involves RegExp later on down the line.

Comment: No, I just didn't understand how you wanted to use them at all; I forgot that `result` does invoke methods instead of returning functions. It is getting clearer now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty bad at providing reduced test cases – thanks for the insight though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a good solution for your question other than using a function expression with explicit arity. Underscore/Lodash don't have methods for fixing the arity of a function, which makes their `partial` and especially `partialRight` functions hard to use. You might want to have a look at [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/R.html#arity) instead.

However, for your use case you don't need such anyway. The appropriate tool is `_.invoke`:

```
function pathFrom(parts) {
    return _.invoke(parts, 'toString').join('/');
}
```

Comment: This solves this particular instance of the problem – thanks for pointing to me to `_.invoke`! I was hoping someone would point me towards forced-arity functionality in lodash (`_.curry` does it for the sake of knowing when to execute given less arguments, but doesn't enforce it). Thanks for the pointer to R – looks very rich!

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI lodash now has a [_.ary](https://lodash.com/docs#ary) function that does what you're looking for.

```
var path = require('path');
[ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ].map(_.ary(path.resolve, 1)); 
// => [ '/<cwd>/foo', '/<cwd>/bar', '/<cwd>/baz' ]
```

Comment: also just to be clear the `require('path')` comes from [node](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)